# SQL - Find % of users who made purchase in Feb 2020

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have 2 tables:

```
Table A: User (users who made purchase) - user_id, date, product_id
Table B: Country - user_id, country
```

I want to find out the % of users in the US who made purchase in Feb

I think below query should work, but I got warning from my friend that it may not be working as expected (may get extra records/rows)..So I just wanted to double check with experts here :)

```
select count(distinct b.user_id) / count(distinct a.user_id)
from country a
left join user b on a.user_id = b.user_id and date_trunc('month',date) = '2020-02-01' --don't worry about the date format
where a.country = 'US'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
select (count(distinct case when date_trunc('month',date) = '2020-02-01' then u.user_id) * 1.0 /
        count(distinct u.user_id)
       ) as ratio
from country c join
     user u
     on c.user_id = u.user_id a
where c.country = 'US'
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes this will work. But can you check if my query is actually correct or not?

Comment: @user12562215 . . . You don't explain what the data looks like, so it is hard to tell.  I might work.

Comment: As I'm revisiting this, I feel we should use left join instead. Not every user from `country` table has made purcahse (thus not necessarily in `user` table